# href javascript is not working on my image

Tags: javascript

I'm adding images stored in firebase to my html page from the database. That works and the image shows up, but I am unable to make the href property work on the img element. I want it to be clickable. Suggestions what I am doing wrong here?

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = snapshot.child("urlToImage " + (i) + " Content").val();
img.href = snapshot.child("urlToImage " + (i) + " Content").val();
img.height = 30;
img.width = 30;
contentA[i].appendChild(img);
```

Comment: Images don't have `href` attributes; anchors do

Comment: You nned to wrap an <a> element around the img - or ass a click event handler to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clickable image

```js
function clickMe(){
   alert('Clicked!');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
An image as a link: 
<a onclick="clickMe()">
  <img src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/live-resource/productCategories/HF-AT/HF_PRINT_WEB_F781A5E7-1575-4D81-8317-BC51C8653EBB.jpeg" border="0" alt="W3Schools" src="logo_w3s.gif" width="100" height="100">
</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the `img` element in an `a` tag.

```
<a href='urlToImage'><img src='urlToImage' /></a>
```

You can of course have an `href` attribute on an `img` if you want to, it just doesn't have any special default meaning to browsers like it would on an anchor

Comment: It still doesn't click. I did this <a href="http://www.spinteractive.net"><div id="A_Inside_Bus1_Content-div"/></a>. The content displays but no click.

Answer (score 0):

Is href a valid attribute of img? I've never seen that before. If you want it to be clickable just wrap it in a anchor.

Comment: Good question, I saw an example doing that and intellisense let me with no compile errors. But now that I think about it, it's not.

Comment: What I meant by valid, is does it have inherent meaning like href on anchor, and I think the asnwer is no. So if you saw someone using it they were using it as a custom attribute (in which case its valid whatever its name). A better name for somehting like that would be data-url or such. That is especially useful in jquery where you grab a bunch of elements by class, and attach an onclick to them. Then you can just reference this.attr('data-url') in the onclick say to give each a different link.